# How do I create a X-windows window independent of the current window manager?

Tags: linux, x11

I am playing with X-windows, Xlib, etc. I want to create a X-window independent of the window-manager: meaning that I do not want the WM to put a frame, minimize-maximize, close, menu, title-bar, etc. in the window. I want to create a vanilla X window. How?

[edit]
Alternatively, how to I capture those events so my windowing app can at least die without an error?

[edit] ninjalj's answer led me to the following info:

[ICCCM](http://tronche.com/gui/x/icccm/sec-4.html)
[Lots & lots of info](http://www.rahul.net/kenton/xsites.framed.html) :) cool! 
[Tutorial](http://xopendisplay.hilltopia.ca/2009/Jan/Xlib-tutorial-part-1----Beginnings.html)

Comment: There are "hints" that you can set on a window that tells the window manager not to decorate it, but window managers are free to ignore the hints.

Comment: Besides ICCCM, there is also NetWM / EWMH (http://standards.freedesktop.org/wm-spec/wm-spec-1.4.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want is an override-redirect window. Just set the override-redirect on your XSetWindowAttributes struct (and the corresponding bit on valuemask) when creating the window.

Comment: wooof! okay, got it working. Facing the battle between: "this is my computer & I want to do whatever to it" vs "play nicely now". Interesting (& fun) doing X-development ;) thanks.